# How to filter values in a column with common values in another common and apply two conditions in the filtering

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'patient': ['patient1', 'patient1', 'patient1','patient2', 'patient2', 'patient3','patient3','patient4'], 
                   'gene':['TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR'],
                   'variant': ['buu', 'luu', 'stm','lol', 'bla', 'buu', 'lol','buu'],
                    'genotype': ['hom', 'het', 'hom','het', 'hom', 'het', 'het','het']})
df

 patient    gene    variant genotype
0   patient1    TYR buu hom
1   patient1    TYR luu het
2   patient1    TYR stm hom
3   patient2    TYR lol het
4   patient2    TYR bla hom
5   patient3    TYR buu het
6   patient3    TYR lol het
7   patient4    TYR buu het
```

I want to identify patients who have buu and additional variants BUT not luu. So, the expected output should be like this

```
patient gene variant genotype

patient3  TYR     buu      het
patient3  TYR     lol      het
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try the following solution:

```
import pandas as pd

# First we filter out those groups that have only 1 observations
g = df.groupby('patient').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)

# Then we apply both of our desired conditions
m = (g.groupby('patient')['variant'].transform(lambda x: x.eq('buu').any() & (~ x.eq('luu').any())))

g.loc[m]

    patient gene variant genotype
5  patient3  TYR     buu      het
6  patient3  TYR     lol      het
```

Answer (score 2):

##### using `set` operations:

```
# aggregate the variants as sets
g = df.groupby('patient')['variant'].agg(set)

# keep the patients with more than "buu" but not "luu"
keep = g.index[g.gt({'buu'}) & ~g.ge({'luu'})]
# ['patient3']

# index rows of the above patients
out = df[df['patient'].isin(keep)]
```

Output:

```
    patient gene variant genotype
5  patient3  TYR     buu      het
6  patient3  TYR     lol      het
```

Intermediates:

```
g

patient
patient1    {buu, stm, luu}
patient2         {bla, lol}
patient3         {buu, lol}
patient4              {buu}
Name: variant, dtype: object


g.gt({'buu'})  # g > {'buu'}

patient
patient1     True
patient2    False
patient3     True
patient4    False
Name: variant, dtype: bool


~g.ge({'luu'}) # ~(g>={'luu'})

patient
patient1    False
patient2     True
patient3     True
patient4     True
Name: variant, dtype: bool
```

##### using [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)

```
m = (
 df.assign(has_buu=df['variant'].eq('buu'),
           not_luu=df['variant'].ne('luu'),
           other=~df['variant'].isin(['buu', 'luu'])
          )
   .groupby('patient')
   .agg({'has_buu': 'any', 'not_luu': 'all', 'other': 'any'})
)

out = df[df['patient'].isin(m.index[m.all(axis=1)])]
```

Output:

```
    patient gene variant genotype
5  patient3  TYR     buu      het
6  patient3  TYR     lol      het
```

Intermediate:

```
m

          has_buu  not_luu  other
patient                          
patient1     True    False   True
patient2    False     True   True
patient3     True     True   True
patient4     True     True  False
```

Comment: Was there any issue with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a one line solution, but I would rather construct one, so you can understand the logic behind it. You want to get all patient's who doesn't have 'luu' variant. In the database world the easier approach would be to get all that *have* 'luu' and divide it from the original db.

*1. Get the patients with 'luu' variant:*

```
patients = list(df[df['variant'] == 'luu']['patient'])
```

This will return a list of patients that have 'luu' as variant.

*Get all entries that belong to the other patients:*

```
df = df[~df.patient.isin(patients)]
```

For your input you would get:

```
df
    patient gene variant genotype
3  patient2  TYR     lol      het
4  patient2  TYR     bla      hom
5  patient3  TYR     buu      het
6  patient3  TYR     lol      het
7  patient4  TYR     buu      het
```

From this point I'm not entirely sure how you can expect your expected output from "I want to identify patients who have buu and additional variants BUT not luu." But if you want to get multiple expressions at once than you could do something like:

```
df[~df.patient.isin(patients)][df.genotype == 'het']
```

For this it will return:

```
    patient gene variant genotype
3  patient2  TYR     lol      het
5  patient3  TYR     buu      het
6  patient3  TYR     lol      het
7  patient4  TYR     buu      het
```